# How to pass id to controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I using this method to upload the image and passing the page id so i can store the path into database but having error "Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\RoundtablesController::postImage()"

This is my form

```
<div class="btn-group">
                        {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'RoundtablesController@postImage',$tables->id, 'files'=>true)) !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('Profile-Picture', 'Profile Picture:') !!}
                            {!! Form::file('profile_image',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
```

This is my route

```
Route::post('/roundtables/settings',['uses'=>'RoundtablesController@postImage','middleware'=>['auth']]);
```

This is my controller ,the $name should get the Page Id, but look like the id not passed to here yet

```
public function postImage(Request $request,$name){
    $table_details =Detail::find($name);
    //save image
    if ($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {
        //add new photo
        $image = $request->file('profile_image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);
        $oldFilename = $table_details->profile_image;

        //update database
        $table_details->profile_image = $filename;
        //Delete old image
        Storage::delete($oldFilename);
    }
    $table_details->update();
```

Can i know where is the error? Sry i know this is very basic but i am new in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route:

```
Route::post('/roundtables/settings/{id}',
    ['as' => 'roundtables.setting',
     'middleware'=>['auth'],
     'uses'=>'RoundtablesController@postImage']);
```

Action:

```
public function postImage(Request $request, $id) {
  $Detail = Detail::findOrFail($id); // will return 404 or exception if record not found

  if ($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {
    $file = $request->file('profile_image');
    $profile_image = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $profile_image_file = public_path('images/' . $profile_image);
    Image::make($image)
           ->resize(800, 400)
           ->save($profile_image_file);

    $old_profile_image_file = public_path('images/'.$Detail->profile_image);

    if(is_file($profile_image_file)) { // if new file successfully created
      $Detail->profile_image = $profile_image; // changing profile_image
      $Detail->save(); // saving
      Storage::delete($old_profile_image_file);
    }
  }
}
```

in view open form like (use named route: `roundtables.setting` defined in router):

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => route('roundtables.setting', $tables->id), 'files'=>true)) !!}
```

also it's a little bit strange `$tables->id`, are You sure that `$tables` is an instance of model (not an array or collection) ?

Comment: Now having new error after changing my code, "Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: roundtables/settings/{id}]". Is my form not passing id?

Comment: @masterhunter updated my answer check now, also please put Your action where You're getting `$tables` and passing to view.

Comment: route('rountables.setting', $tables->id) got typo error, but yes is working, thank you for help. I am not familiar in passing data yet.

Comment: sorry my fault, typo: `rountables` => `roundtables`

Comment: happy that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

route should be like

```
Route::post('/roundtables/settings/{name}',['uses'=>'RoundtablesController@postImage','middleware'=>['auth']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

Route::get('groups/(:any)', array('as' => 'group', 'uses' => 'groups@show'));

```
class Groups_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;    

    public function get_show($groupID) {
        return 'I am group id ' . $groupID;
    }  


}
```